# Does .then wait for setState to finish before calling the next method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this method in my React app:

My issue is that the `createQuestions()` runs before the `findEmployeeId()` method is done. Shouldn't the `.then` make it wait?

Inside the `findEmployeeId()` it is doing a `setState` operation.  Does it not wait for that to finish?  I need that data update before the `createQuestions()` runs.

```
createInterview() {
    fetch(API_URL + `/interview/create`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        employee: this.state.employee,
        employment_level: this.state.employment_level,
        audit_id: this.props.auditId,
      }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .then(() => this.findEmployeeId())
      .then(() => this.createQuestions());

    this.setState({ showHide: false });
  }
```

This is the `findEmployeeId` method.  How can I make it wait until completion before the next one runs?

```
findEmployeeId() {
    fetch(API_URL + `/employee/${this.state.employee}/${this.props.auditId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ lastEmployeeId: result[0].employee_id });
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: > Shouldn't the .then make it wait? - No, unless findEmployeeId returns a Promise.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The question is basically finding a way to guarantee to have createQuestions() executed after findEmployeeId(). This is the heart of the question. The use of the setState Callback can make this to happen. It is said that the use of the setState call back could be cumbersome but if there is a good understanding about composition of two functions then this should not be.

setState is asynchronous... so it is important to not make assumptions on sequentiality for two ops like:

```
this.setState({stateA : a})
this.setState({stateB : b})
```

The only way to "force" sequentiality through setState is through its call back:

this.setState({ .... }, () => {do after setState is done})

Somehow this is what you need to follow i.e. at the setState you are using inside findEmployeID it is necessary to do something like:

```
const self = this;
this.setState({ ..... }, () => {self.createQuestions()})
```

Whoever placed that negative better explain his reason. The .then part of the fetch does not guaranty sequentiality so it falls to the situation similar where two setStates are executed one after the other. A wait also does not guaranty sequentiality.

Comment: Makes sense and that did the trick.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

@raina77ow wrote it in his comment already, but to state it a little more clearly, I think you need to return the promise from findEmployeeId():

```
findEmployeeId() {
    /* Note the return here */
    return fetch(API_URL + `/employee/${this.state.employee}/${this.props.auditId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ lastEmployeeId: result[0].employee_id });
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Comment: The question is basically finding a way to guarantee to have createQuestions() executed after findEmployeeId(). This is the heart of the question. The use of the setState Callback makes this happen. It is said that the use of the setState call back could be cumbersome but if there is a good understanding about composition of two functions then this should not be.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga I humbly disagree. I interpret the question to be mainly about why the code does not work as intended. I still contend that it is because the promise it not returned from the function. Stuff like this is easily overlooked and that is the main reason I use typescript myself.

Comment: The question said: "I need that data update before the createQuestions() runs."